# Exporting php to excel, text-aligment not working

Tags: php, html, css, excel

Hi guys i have been experiencing a rare alignment while exporting php table to excel.
I have set text-alignment:left but still not working. 
I have also searched for cell alignment but haven't found the solution.

Here is an image of my table without exporting it to vnd-ms-excel:
[image]

And while exporting this happens:

[image]

I don't know why the excel file has this alignment, i will add my code but is not pretty clean so i will show the header:

```
// The function header by sending raw excel
    header("Content-type: application/vnd-ms-excel");

// Defines the name of the export file "codelution-export.xls"
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=horarios-$fecha.xls");
```

And this is the part of my code where I add style to my table:

```
echo '<style>table {width:595px;text-align:left;}
table{border-collapse: collapse;}table,th,td{border:1px solid #000;}</style>';
```

As you can see in the second image some text is aligned left, other right and other centered.

Comment: If you have a cell with only a number, Excel will count it as a number field. Numbers are right aligned in Excel by default.

Comment: Thanks for your response, there is any way to make them left alignment? @MagnusEriksson

Comment: As far as I know, not if you want the value to still be a number (otherwise I think you can do some sneaky stuff like adding some non numeric character before or after the number) and not use any library like PHPExcel.

Comment: @JuanFranciscoGancia Could format them as strings (prepend an apostrophe like `'20`), but that might cause more issues depending on what you want to do later with the numbers.

Comment: @Mikegrann - True. But usually you want the numbers to be real numbers in the final Excel file. I think using a library to create a proper Excel-file is the best way to go.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I acknowledged that. But Excel is funny about implicitly converting types whenever possible, so most things like comparisons and arithmetic will all work as expected. Most VBA macros will handle it without problems, too. The only real issue comes with some types of lookups. Again, depends on what he wants to do with the file.

Answer (score 0):

You can set alignments using [`PHPExcel`](https://phpexcel.codeplex.com/) library. 
these two URLs may help you.

[PHPExcel how to apply alignment for the whole document created from mysql table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12614864/phpexcel-how-to-apply-alignment-for-the-whole-document-created-from-mysql-table)

[PHP Excel - Set cell or Column Direction (RTL)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31422237/php-excel-set-cell-or-column-direction-rtl)